# Split the contents of a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have the following string

```
s = "ΔG'° = (-19.9 +/- 0.4) kilojoule / mole"
```

I'd like to generate a dictionary like the following

```
d = {"mean"= -19.9, "sd": 0.4, "units": "kilojoule / mole"}
```

If the string is `-19.9 +/- 0.4` I could do `s.split("+/-")`. But in the given format, I have
to split several times based on each delimiter.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Are all your strings in this format? Because then you can build a regular expression that solves each part.

Comment: @Thymen Yes, all in this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
r'=[^\d-]*(?P<mean>-?\d*\.?\d+)\s*\+/-\s*(?P<sd>\d*\.?\d+)\W+(?P<units>.+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RaC1Xl/1/). Details:

- `=` - a `=` sign
- `[^\d-]*` - zero or more chars other than digit and `-`
- `(?P<mean>-?\d*\.?\d+)` - Group "mean": an optional `-`, zero or more digits, an optional `.` and then one or more digits
- `\s*\+/-\s*` - a `+/-` substring enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(?P<sd>\d*\.?\d+)` - Group "sd": zero or more digits, an optional `.` and then one or more digits
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `(?P<units>.+)` - Group "units": the rest of the string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/r7oF1G):

```py
import re
rx = r'=[^\d-]*(?P<mean>-?\d*\.?\d+)\s*\+/-\s*(?P<sd>\d*\.?\d+)\W+(?P<units>.+)'
text = r"ΔG'° = (-19.9 +/- 0.4) kilojoule / mole"
m = re.search(rx, text)
if m:
    print(m.groupdict())
# => {'mean': '-19.9', 'sd': '0.4', 'units': 'kilojoule / mole'}
```

Comment: The link is not working for me, but I created an alternative link [here](https://regex101.com/r/7ast0e/1) using regex101.

Comment: @Thymen I double-checked, it must be working now.

Comment: Yes I replied before the regex demo link, but the `Python demo` link is not working for me.

Comment: @Thymen It does for me... The link is https://ideone.com/r7oF1G

Comment: Apparently using a VPN blocks that site, disabling it will allow me to see the content.

Comment: @Thymen Ok, here is a [link to a Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/HADR80977).